# cannot read property swing of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I am using the CDN version of [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- page body -->

        <!-- scripts -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and getting the following error in console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'swing' of undefined
>
> at materialize.min.js:6
>
> (anonymous) @ materialize.min.js:6

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It looks like Materialize uses extend, so you'll need the full version of jQuery - the slim version will not work.

Comment: Fixed my jQuery easing problem with BS4 :). Boostrap uses the slim version by default I changed to the full jQuery and voila!

Answer (score 4):

When you use material Design Bootstrap,

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.4.1/css/mdb.min.css" />
</head>
```

AND Put Script File at end of "body" section:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.4.1/js/mdb.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Don't forget to use uncompressed version of JQuery as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the Jquery.slim to a normal Jquery. It works with me

Answer (score 1):

Use 'jquery-3.5.1.min.js' instead of 'jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js'.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using the updated version of the CDN worked for me. In the MDBootstrap website

```
  <script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/5.0.0/mdb.min.js"
></script>
```